# make textarea not wrap when using specific symbols

Tags: html, css, textarea, word-wrap

I have a textarea I am using for an ASCII art 3d game and when there are different types of characters, it wraps even though I have set all the css wrapping stuff to no wrap. It's only meant to wrap at the end of each line and not in between different characters.

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5em;
  font-size: 14px;

  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#expected {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>actual:</p>
<textarea wrap="hard">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<</textarea>
<p>expected:</p>
<div id="expected">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa(((((((((((((((((((((((<br>(((((((>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<br><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<</div>
```

I have tried every other question but all the answers just did words and not symbols.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use the css `calc()` to convert it to `ch` unit.

```css
textarea {
  width: calc(300px - 0px);
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;

}
```

```html
<textarea wrap="hard">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((




expected:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa999999999999999999999999999999999999fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffssssssssssssssssssssssssssss11111111111111111111111111</textarea>
```

Comment: its only meant to wrap at the end of the line and not in between characters

Comment: @GiantBooley, what do you mean by at the end of the line? it is so confusing like your expected is much different than the input one

Comment: i edited the snippet to make it more clear

Comment: @GiantBooley, got it now. I edited the code